# Sinatra session gets destroyed automatically

Tags: ruby, session, facebook, sinatra

I'm not sure why but my session gets wiped out every request.

This is my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'haml'
require 'facebook_oauth'
class MyClass < Sinatra::Base
  set :logging, true
  set :sessions, true
  get "/auth/facebook_callback" do

    // Do some facebook login which is fine    

    access_token = facebookClient.authorize(:code => params[:code])
    session[:access_token] = access_token.token
    session[:user] = facebookClient.me.info['name']
    session[:id] = facebookClient.me.info["id"]
    #print session by "pp session" I can still see all the sessions
    redirect '/'
  end

  get '/' do
    #print all the sessions again. And I can't see anything. The session_id is also different
  end
end
```

Comment: If I simplify your code and run it here, it works. Any additional data you can provide? Sorry to ask this, but cookies *are* enabled in the browser, right? Did you try to take a look at the HTTP headers?

Comment: The session being reset suggests to me that it's something to do with [attack protection](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuring%20attack%20protection). Try adding `disable :protection` and see if that changes anything. (I wouldn't recommend leaving protection disabled, but it might help you determine what's going on).

Comment: Thank you both of you, I just checked and I was running Shotgun so the server is restarted every time.

Answer (score 7):

To keep sessions consistent you need to set a session secret, e.g.:

```
set :session_secret, 'super secret'
```

When it's not set sinatra generates random one on application start and shotgun restarts application before every request.

Comment: This was the solution to 5 hours of debugging!